# Magento model->save() does not work

Tags: magento

I am using following code for saving data from form to database.

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
$custom['name'] = $data['name'];

$model = Mage::getModel('my/custom_order');
$model->setOrderId($order_id);
$model->setKey('name');
$model->setValue(serialize($custom));
$model->save();
```

Data does not save in database.But When I pass static data like below, It is Working.

```
$custom['name'] = 'John';
```

When I use print_r($data),

```
Array(
[name] => xyz
[surname] => 
)
```

Comment: Check how `$data` looks like. Maybe the 'name' is not filled in and it cannot be `null`. Also check `var/log` for error messages.

Comment: When I use `print_r($data);`,It give me array with value.But In system.log file, It give me error Notice: Undefined index: name.

Comment: Just like I suspected. The `name` is not filled in. Post the `$data` array in the question to get a better view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()->getParams();
```

Please check this. Check data which sended to server in your browser Network tool.

Answer (score -1):

You need

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```